# KOMA-Script - Include section title on the first page of the chapter

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I would like to have section title displayed on the header. However on the first page of the chapter, only chapter title is included. How can I include section title on the first page?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\ohead*{\rightmark}
\chead*{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The First Chapter}

\section{The First Section}
\lipsum

\section{The Second Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: \rightmark is the first right mark, and this is set by the chapter. It would require some fiddling to store and retrieve the first section title instead. But I wouldn't use a header on the first chapter page at all. It simply looks bad, and every publisher will tell you to suppress the header there anyway.

Comment: You could use `\rightbotmark`. Then the last right mark on a page is displayed in header.  But I also would not use a header on chapter pages.